# pthread and fopen64 segfaults on fgets

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, large-files

I'm using Kubuntu 12.04, gcc 4.6.3.
If I create a pthread, use fopen64 and then fgets - it segfaults.
Same code replacing fopen64 with fopen - it succeeds.
Without creating pthread - it succeeds.
So why the failure?  Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
typedef struct threadArgs
{
    char* argsList;
    int argc;
} threadArgs;

void 
threadRun(void *pArg);

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int err = 0;
    threadArgs thrArgs;
    pthread_t thrd;  

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        printf("creating thread \n");
        err = pthread_create (&thrd, NULL, (void *) &threadRun, (void *) &thrArgs);
        printf("pthread_create returned: %d \n", err);
        pthread_join(thrd, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no thread - just calling func \n");
        threadRun((void*)&thrArgs);
    }
    printf("Exiting main() \n");

    return err;
}

void 
threadRun(void *pArg)
{
    printf("IN the Thread \n");
    char* pStr;
    FILE *pFile = NULL;

    pFile = (FILE*)fopen64("test.txt","r");
    //pFile = (FILE*)fopen("test.txt","r");

    if (pFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("pFile is NULL \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("pFile is NOT null \n");
        char line[256];
        pStr = fgets(line, sizeof(line),pFile);
        if (pStr)
        {
            printf("line retrieved: %s \n", line);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no line retrieved \n");
        }
    }   

    printf("End of pthread run func \n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you remove the `(FILE*)` cast of `fope64` and try again?

Comment: Do you have a prototype for `fopen64()` included from somewhere? Or: Why do you cast `fopen64()`?

Comment: Remove all castings (as your code does not need them), then recompile with all warnings on and fix your code until you do not get any wanrings anymore. Then come back and tell us about the outcome ... :-)

Comment: Few checks, does `file <executable>` show that its a 64 bit executable? Does `ldd <executable>` show the libraries it depends on are 64 bit libraries (libc, libpthread etc)? What does `gdb` show?

Comment: @William, removed the cast but same results.

Comment: @alk, warning with cast:
  cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

warning without cast:
  assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
So I'm unsure HOW to remove this warning!

Comment: @another, 
$ file pThreadTst 
pThreadTst: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked (uses shared libs), 
for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xedc3052f825b1a53a93098f6d55c74db3c0d6a06, not stripped
$ ldd pThreadTst 
  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff831ff000)
  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb95d263000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb95cea4000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb95d49b000)
As for "what does gdb show?", I'm using KDevelop4. What specifically   should I try?

Comment: I didn't realize that fopen combined with a compiler flag will accomplish the same as fopen64 (see: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/149806-difference-between-fopen-fopen64.html).
So at least I can move onward. And fopen gives no warnings.
Its just peculiar this "bug"... I don't like unsolved mysteries.

Comment: Do not use `fopen64()`, as there is not prototype available for it in your build environment. Please see my answer. @SkippyVonDrake

Comment: @alk, I'm unsure how to edit the original post to make it more clear. If I do NOT use pthread_create() and still call the function using fopen64() - then it succeeds. Only when combined WITH pthread_create does it segfault on the fgets() call. So fopen64 is definitely available.

Comment: Do not change your post. This would make the whole thread her ununderstanable. Adding some updates is ok. Btw: see my answer for a solution to your problem.

Comment: @alk, I added the define you posted - no difference in warnings and no difference in results. Have you executed this program as is successfully? Note I add an input parameter to direct the flow to create a pthread. Otherwise it just calls the function from the main thread.

Comment: No issues on my side. Please see `Update 2` of my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pthread_create()` expects `void * (*)(void *)` as thread function, but you are passing `void (*)(void *)`.

---

**Update:**

You are missing a prototype for `fopen64()`, so the compiler assumes `int` which is not the same as `FILE*`.

---

**Update 1:**

To have this prototype available (and with this fix you initial problem) just add:

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
```

as first line in your source file.

*Additional edit:* To be exact: `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` needs to `#define`ed before `#include`ing `stdio.h`

---

**Update 2:**

Following the sources I used to make the suxxer work (`main.c`):

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct threadArgs
{
    char* argsList;
    int argc;
} threadArgs;

void *
threadRun(void *pArg);

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) /* line 16 */
{
    int err = 0;
    threadArgs thrArgs;
    pthread_t thrd;

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        printf("creating thread \n");
        err = pthread_create (&thrd, NULL, threadRun, &thrArgs);
        printf("pthread_create returned: %d \n", err);
        pthread_join(thrd, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("no thread - just calling func \n");
        threadRun((void*)&thrArgs);
    }
    printf("Exiting main() \n");

    return err;
}

void  *
threadRun(void *pArg)  /* line 40 */
{
    printf("IN the Thread \n");
    char* pStr;
    FILE *pFile = NULL;

    pFile = fopen64("test.txt","r");

    if (pFile==NULL)
    {
        printf("pFile is NULL \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("pFile is NOT null \n");
        char line[256];
        pStr = fgets(line, sizeof(line),pFile);
        if (pStr)
        {
            printf("line retrieved: %s \n", line);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("no line retrieved \n");
        }
    }

    printf("End of pthread run func \n");

    return 0;
}
```

build by:

```
$gcc -Wall -g -o main main.c -pedantic -Wextra -std=c99 -pthread 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:16: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’
main.c: In function ‘threadRun’:
main.c:40: warning: unused parameter ‘pArg’
```

(no other errors or  warnings)

enviroment:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian-stable 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5
[...]
$ ldd main
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff466d6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f15ccd20000)
        ibc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f15cc9be000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f15ccf4b000)
```

The output (using `main.c`'s source without `\n`s as `test.txt`):

```
$ valgrind ./main 1
==31827== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31827== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31827== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31827== Command: ./main 1
==31827== 
creating thread 
pthread_create returned: 0 
IN the Thread 
pFile is NOT null 
line retrieved: #define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE #include <stdio.h> #include <pthread.h> typedef struct threadArgs { char* argsList; int argc; } threadArgs; void * threadRun(void *pArg); int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { int err = 0; threadArgs thrArgs; pthread_t thrd; if (a 
End of pthread run func 
Exiting main() 
==31827== 
==31827== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31827==     in use at exit: 568 bytes in 1 blocks
==31827==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 840 bytes allocated
==31827== 
==31827== LEAK SUMMARY:
==31827==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31827==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31827==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31827==    still reachable: 568 bytes in 1 blocks
==31827==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31827== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==31827== 
==31827== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31827== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: pthread_create() never failed in this example - at least for me. But I changed void to void* anyways just to be sure. The segfault happens only at the fgets() call within the thread function.

Comment: Note that while returning `void` instead of `void*` won't cause major issues on x86 or x86-64 (though it's still wrong), on [IA64, uninitialized garbage can be deadly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx).

Comment: @alk, My bad! I had the define "_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE" AFTER the "include <stdio.h>". Which of course wouldn't do it much good.
After putting it first - like you specified - the fgets no longer segfaults. Thanks, alk, for going the extra mile!